# Grabbing data from Netlify CMS folder

Tags: reactjs, content-management-system, netlify

I have successfully linked the netlify cms backend to my react frontend, however now my main problem is figuring out how to display said data from its folder _posts to my react frontend.

```
 MySite
 | _posts
    | blog
      /2020-06-23-my-post.md
 | public
```

config.yml

```
backend:
  name: git-gateway
  branch: master 

media_folder: "public/images" # Media files will be stored in the repo under static/images/uploads
public_folder: "/images"

collections:
  - name: "blog" # Used in routes, e.g., /admin/collections/blog
    label: "Blog" # Used in the UI
    folder: "_posts/blog" # The path to the folder where the documents are stored
    create: true # Allow users to create new documents in this collection
    slug: "{{year}}-{{month}}-{{day}}-{{slug}}" # Filename template, e.g., YYYY-MM-DD-title.md
    fields: # The fields for each document, usually in front matter
      - {label: "Layout", name: "layout", widget: "hidden", default: "blog"}
      - {label: "Title", name: "title", widget: "string"}
      - {label: "Publish Date", name: "date", widget: "datetime"}
      - {label: "Featured Image", name: "thumbnail", widget: "image"}
      - {label: "Rating (scale of 1-5)", name: "rating", widget: "number"}
      - {label: "Body", name: "body", widget: "markdown"}
```

Comment: Have you figured out already?

Answer (score 0):

Assume you have set your `static/admin/config.yml` for blog post like below

```yaml
  
backend:
  name: github
  repo: ozluy/destan-nakliyat-gatsby
  branch: master
media_folder: static/assets
public_folder: /assets
site_url: https://destan-nakliyat.netlify.app
collections:
  - name: post
    label: Post
    folder: post
    create: true
    fields:
      - { name: path, label: Path }
      - { name: date, label: Date, widget: datetime }
      - { name: title, label: Title }
      - { name: body, label: Body, widget: markdown }
```

with `gatsby-source-filesystem` plugin you can use set your plugin settings as below in `gatsby-config.js` like this:

```js
plugins: [
...,
   {
      resolve: `gatsby-source-filesystem`,
      options: {
        name: `pages`,
        path: `${__dirname}/post/`,
      },
    },
```

finally you can access saved post files through GraphQL as below:

```
{
  allFile {
    edges {
      node {
        extension
        dir
        modifiedTime
      }
    }
  }
}
```